# How do you make text show on a form when you click on the submit button in jquery?

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Sorry, If this is very simple but I am very new to jquery and can you you please tell me the answer to this code.

```
$("submit").click(function(){
  $("#feedback").show();
});
```

Is this code right and if not then can you please correct me, many thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `$("#submit")`

Comment: There is no HTML element named "submit" so the click is not attaching to anything. Perhaps "input[type=submit]" is desired? Oh, perhaps better, bind to the forms submit event ..

Comment: First of all what are you trying to do? are you trying to hook the submit event on form? is that the case then use 'code'$('#form_id').submit(function(){ $("#feedback").show(); }); Now if you trying to hook to the click event of an anchar tag that is <a id="submit">Click</a> then you should do it like this $('#submit').click(function(){ $('#feedback').show()});

Comment: As much as I love the guessing games, could I skip to the end, and ask if you could post the (relevant/[**sscce**](http://sscce.org/)) HTML that accompanies this jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question I created example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGpDR/)

> ```
> $("#my_form").submit(function(e){
>     e.preventDefault();
>     $("#feedback").show();
> });
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much and you just helped me discover jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

First of all what are you trying to do? are you trying to hook the submit event on form? is that the case then use

```
   $('#form_id').submit(function(){ $("#feedback").show(); });
```

Now if you trying to hook to the click event of an anchar tag that is

```
       <a id="submit">Click</a>
```

then you should do it like this

```
    $('#submit').click(function(){ $('#feedback').show()});
```